# Wrap HTML with DIV until next H3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wrapall

I have the following HTML structure:

```js
$('#subgroup a').nextUntil('h3').wrapAll('<div></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="subgroup">
  <h3>Group name #1</h3>
  <a href="#">Link #1</a>
  <a href="#">Link #2</a>
  <h3>Group name #2</h3>
  <a href="#">Link #3</a>
  <a href="#">Link #4</a>
</div>
```

I have this flat structure because I want to use jQuery UI's accordion effect. I want to wrap all `a` elements between the `h3` elements.

But this caused some of the `a` elements to disappear. I've tried quite a few selectors but none of them has worked. Am I doing this right?

Comment: Why not fix the original markup (instead of having the user's browser do it on every page load)?

Comment: The problem is the CMS which outputs crappy HTML. I would if I could!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An approach like this should work, though I'm guessing there are many different ways of doing this:

```
$('#subgroup h3').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('h3').wrapAll('<div></div>');
});
```

Comment: That didn't work, (yeah I added `<div></div>` in `wrapAall()`. I'll try experimenting with this solution.

Comment: Sorry, I quickly checked that it worked for me by adding `<div style='background-color: red'></div>` and then took too much out when I posted my answer! In what way doesn't it work? What does the HTML look like in Firebug after the jQuery's been run?

Comment: Confirmed this works - makes sense too - for each header, then collect everything and use wrapALL. Tip: nextUntil(':header') worked better for me as I have various header types.

Answer (score -1):

This is what it looks like after some nice (and dirty) jQuerying, to tidy up the HTML:

```
<div id="subgr-productlist">

    <h3>Serie 1000</h3>
    <a id="product-PROD79" href="/global/hygiene/touchfree-dispensers/dispensers/products.aspx?ProductId=PROD79" name="product-PROD79">Model 1010</a>
    <a id="product-PROD80" href="/global/hygiene/touchfree-dispensers/dispensers/products.aspx?ProductId=PROD80" name="product-PROD80">Model 1020</a>
    <a id="product-PROD81" href="/global/hygiene/touchfree-dispensers/dispensers/products.aspx?ProductId=PROD81" name="product-PROD81">Model 1030</a>
    <a id="product-PROD82" href="/global/hygiene/touchfree-dispensers/dispensers/products.aspx?ProductId=PROD82" name="product-PROD82">Model 1040</a>
    <a id="product-PROD83" href="/global/hygiene/touchfree-dispensers/dispensers/products.aspx?ProductId=PROD83" name="product-PROD83">Model 1050</a>

    <h3>Serie 2000</h3>
    <a id="product-PROD234" href="/global/hygiene/touchfree-dispensers/dispensers/products.aspx?ProductId=PROD234" name="product-PROD234">Model 2010</a>

    <h3>Serie 3000</h3>
    <a id="product-PROD85" href="/global/hygiene/touchfree-dispensers/dispensers/products.aspx?ProductId=PROD85" name="product-PROD85">Model 3010</a>

    <h3>Serie 4000</h3>
    <a id="product-PROD86" href="/global/hygiene/touchfree-dispensers/dispensers/products.aspx?ProductId=PROD86" name="product-PROD86">Model 4010</a>
    <a id="product-PROD87" href="/global/hygiene/touchfree-dispensers/dispensers/products.aspx?ProductId=PROD87" name="product-PROD87">Model 4020</a>
    <a id="product-PROD88" href="/global/hygiene/touchfree-dispensers/dispensers/products.aspx?ProductId=PROD88" name="product-PROD88">Model 4030</a>
    <a id="product-PROD89" href="/global/hygiene/touchfree-dispensers/dispensers/products.aspx?ProductId=PROD89" name="product-PROD89">Model 4040</a>

</div>
```

In other words, all the other `a` elements disappear?

Then I run this jQuery script:

```
$('#subgr-productlist h3').each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('h3').wrapAll('<div class="test"></div>');
});
```

But that results in the `#subgr-productlist div` to render like this:

```
<div id="subgr-productlist">
    <h3>Serie 1000</h3>
    <h3>Serie 2000</h3>
    <h3>Serie 3000</h3>
    <div class="test">
        <a id="product-PROD85" href="/global/hygiene/touchfree-dispensers/dispensers/products/products.aspx?ProductId=%20Model%203010" name="product-PROD85"></a>
    </div>
    <h3>Serie 4000</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Odd. I just ran your code on your html, and got the right output. I can't see any reason any elements would disappear just running that code; wrapAll() should never remove anything, and that's the only active function running.

I think something subtle or weird is going on somewhere. Do you have any extra javascript running anywhere? Can you reproduce the problem on a simple webpage with just the html and jQuery you've posted?

Comment: Hmm, I just got it to work myself, and I have NO idea why it wouldn't work earlier. Emptying cache, multiple browsers etc didn't work, but all of a sudden it just worked... I must have overlooked something. Thanks a bunch Matt! :D

Comment: No problem! Sometimes you just need a sanity check :) Hope it carries on working for you.