# Add scrollspy on document with only heading

Tags: jquery, html, scrollspy

I have to add a scrollspy feature on a document which does not have `<div>` or `<section>` but only `<h#>` with `id` attribute.
**I can't modify the raw document structure.** But I can modify it dynamically with JQuery. So I would like to generate `div` with the `id` attribute of my `<h#>` tag and wrap `<h#>` and all element until next same level `<h#>`.

I know that exist `nextUntil()` method and I try this (for test, it's not what I need) :

```
$("h1").each(function()
{
    el = $();
    $(this).nextUntil("h1").clone().appendTo(el);
});
```

But it doesn't work `el` doesn't contain element.
Here I show you what is the structure of my HTML document.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="firstId">First H1 header</h1>
    <!-- Some text, tables, pictures -->

    <h1 id="secondId">Second H1 header</h1>
        <h2 id="thirdId">First H2 header</h2>
        <!-- Some text, tables, pictures -->

    ...
</body>
</html>
```

If you have some ideas or suggestions... Thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
$(function () {
    $('h1').each(function () {
        $(this).nextUntil('h1').add(this).wrapAll('<div />');
    });
});
```

**and also this**

```
$('#subgroup h3').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('h3').wrapAll('<div id="myid" class="myclass"></div>');
});
```

*references*

[Wrap HTML with DIV until next H3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643715/wrap-html-with-div-until-next-h3)

[How to wrap h1 and follow content in div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899698/how-to-wrap-h1-and-follow-content-in-div)